# Acces denied error when trying to save a distribution group

Tags: c#, visual-studio, active-directory

When running the code shown below, I am getting an error that states:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
    System.DirectoryServices.dll. Additional information: Access is denied.

It happens on this line : `Group.Save();`

I have used the username and password in other scripts relating to Active Directory so it does have sufficient access to anything i need it to do. Although, I haven't tried it in relation to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` library before.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 running in admin mode, so there shouldn't be a problem with the command prompt not running in it.

If anyone can give me a heads up as to why it wouldn't be using the credentials when saving, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
try
            {
                using (PrincipalContext PC = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"))
                {             
                    GroupPrincipal Group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PC, "GROUPNAME");
                    DBAccessManager DBAccess = new DBAccessManager();
                    SqlConnection ConnString = new SqlConnection();

                    ConnString.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLCONNECTION"].ToString();
                    List<Employee> SQLEmployees = DBAccess.ReadUserInformation(ConnString.ConnectionString.ToString());

                    foreach (Employee Emp in SQLEmployees)
                    {
                        UserPrincipal PrinicipalUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PC, Emp.USERNAME);
                        UserPrincipal ADUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PC, Emp.USERNAME);
                        if (PrinicipalUser.IsMemberOf(Group) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Emp.SAPLOGIN))
                        {
                            Group.Members.Remove(ADUser);
                        }
                        else if (!PrinicipalUser.IsMemberOf(Group) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Emp.SAPLOGIN))
                        {
                            Group.Members.Add(ADUser);
                        }
                    }
                    Group.Save();                  
                }
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + E.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a permissions issue on the Distribution List