# "Access is denied." Error when Updating Active Directory Group

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPlXV.png)

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 to attempt to edit members of a group in Active Directory. I am using IIS with Pass Through Windows Authentication. This works fine when running using IISExpress in Visual Studio but when I push it to IIS calling the group.save(); function I get the error: Exception:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.UpdateGroupMembership(Principal group, DirectoryEntry de, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Update(Principal p)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()

Comment: Can [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017757/acces-denied-error-when-trying-to-save-a-distribution-group) help?

Comment: Hmm, we have gone over permissions, which permission would it be? We have it set so the group manager can edit membership.